# Detecting if I have already alerted a message

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a page that loads some data into a model and one of the properties of the model has an errormessage. I have a js file that checks if the errormessage is there; if so, it displays an alert with the message itself like this:

```
function CheckErrMsg(model) { 
    if (model.CallStatusStatus() == -111) {
        alert(model.CallStatusErrorMessage());
    }
}
```

Whenever I'm done doing whatever with the object I have loaded it automatically loads another one and if this checks out for the new model then it will display the alert again.

I want the alert to be displayed only for the first model loaded, so I guess I need to know if there is a way to check if that alert was already displayed and if so don't display it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `IsAlertShown` field to the model then check it before alerting:

```
model.IsAlertShown = ko.observable(false);

if (!model.IsAlertShown() && model.CallStatusStatus() == -111) {
    model.IsAlertShown(true);
    alert(model.CallStatusErrorMessage());
}
```

Yet, personally I don't like to 'pollute' my View-Model (which is usually about to be sent back to the server) with stuff that are purely UI-related. So I would expose the flag as part of the function itself:

```
if (!CheckErrMsg.IsAlertShown && model.CallStatusStatus() == -111) {
    CheckErrMsg.IsAlertShown = true;
    alert(model.CallStatusErrorMessage());
}
```

(Since in JavaScript functions are also objects, you can set properties on functions as well)

Comment: CheckErrMsg would have to be a global variable right?

Comment: `CheckErrMsg` is your `function CheckErrMsg() {}`.

Comment: oh lol yeah I got it... I changed the name of the function to post it so thats why I didnt really got it the first time... thanks ima try that...

Answer (score 0):

Just set a flag:

```
messageDisplayed=0;

function CheckErrMsg(model) { 

if (model.CallStatusStatus() == -111 && messageDisplayed==0) {
        alert(model.CallStatusErrorMessage());
messageDisplayed=1;
    }
}
```

That'll do the trick.

Comment: No need to pollute the global namespace, but otherwise, yes.

Comment: how can I do this without having to add a global variable? or is that the only way?

Comment: The only other way would be to add a hidden form field, and check/set the status there.  No need for a variable then.  And it would work just as well.